# Jquery Two setInterval Conflict with each other

Tags: jquery

I have an image map that is linked to hidden divs. I want the item in the image map to highlight and the hidden div corresponding to that area to show too.

I am using imagemapster.js to highlight the areas in the map. To cycle through the highlights I am using this:

```
var $anchors = jQuery('area'), counter = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function(A){
jQuery($anchors).mapster('deselect');
jQuery($anchors).eq(counter++ % $anchors.length).mapster('select');
}, 5000);
```

It works great. But when I add the code to cycle through the hidden divs which is:

```
var $text = jQuery('.visible'), counter = 0;
var timertwo = setInterval(function(B){
jQuery($text).addClass('hidden');
jQuery($text).eq(counter++ % $text.length).removeClass('hidden');
}, 5000);
```

Then then instead of increments of 1 it loops through selecting every other item.

Is there a way to combine these two functions into one so they increment one at a time and at the same time to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should use two separate counters to avoid interference and two
>   different `$(function(){...});`

```
$(function() {
    var $anchors = jQuery('area'), counter1 = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(function(A){
    jQuery($anchors).mapster('deselect');
    jQuery($anchors).eq(counter1++ % $anchors.length).mapster('select');
    }, 5000);
}
$(function() {
    var $text = jQuery('.visible'), counter2 = 0;
    var timertwo = setInterval(function(B){
    jQuery($text).addClass('hidden');
    jQuery($text).eq(counter2++ % $text.length).removeClass('hidden');
    }, 5000);
}
```